# Seeking alternative ways to have different headers in an array of arrays in Swift

Tags: swift, header, overriding

I have a program that fully works except I was given a note about something that needed changed.

This program contains an array of arrays. In the app each section has a different header. The header names are in a separate array called "myTitles". The user wants the headers to not be using any override methods. How do I change this? The way I have it is the only way I have ever done it.

I was told; "The title (headers) should be a string."

Array of Arrays code (for reference):

```
var emojis: [[Emoji]] = [
            
            [Emoji(symbol: "", name: "Grinning Face", description: "A typical smiley face.", usage: "happiness"),
            Emoji(symbol: "", name: "Confused Face", description: "A confused, puzzled face.", usage: "unsure what to think; displeasure"),
            Emoji(symbol: "", name: "Heart Eyes", description: "A smiley face with hearts for eyes.", usage: "love of something; attractive"),
            Emoji(symbol: "", name: "Police Officer", description: "A police officer wearing a blue cap with a gold badge. He is smiling, and eager to help.", usage: "person of authority")],
            
            
            [Emoji(symbol: "", name: "Turtle", description: "A cute turtle.", usage: "Something slow"),
            Emoji(symbol: "", name: "Elephant", description: "A gray elephant.", usage: "good memory")],
            
            
            [Emoji(symbol: "", name: "Spaghetti", description: "A plate of spaghetti.", usage: "spaghetti")],
             
             
            [Emoji(symbol: "", name: "Die", description: "A single die.", usage: "taking a risk, chance; game"),
            Emoji(symbol: "⛺️", name: "Tent", description: "A small tent.", usage: "camping"),
            Emoji(symbol: "", name: "Stack of Books", description: "Three colored books stacked on each other.", usage: "homework, studying"),
            Emoji(symbol: "", name: "Broken Heart", description: "A red, broken heart.", usage: "extreme sadness"),
            Emoji(symbol: "", name: "Snore", description: "Three blue \'z\'s.", usage: "tired, sleepiness"),
            Emoji(symbol: "", name: "Checkered Flag", description: "A black and white checkered flag.", usage: "completion")]
        ]
```

Header Array:

```
let myTitles: [String] = ["PEOPLE", "ANIMALS", "FOOD", "OTHER"]
```

Code in Question (current header override methods):

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
            let headerView = UIView.init(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.frame.width, height: 50))
            
            let label = UILabel()
            label.frame = CGRect.init(x: 5, y: 5, width: headerView.frame.width-10, height: headerView.frame.height-10)
            label.text = myTitles[section]
            label.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 14)
            label.textColor = .gray
            headerView.addSubview(label)
            
            return headerView
        }
        
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
            return 40
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the optional datasource method
`func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,  titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String?`

and just return the string from your array, rather than forming it into a view.

(FWIW I prefer your approach!)

Comment: I got the code working with your suggestion, but it errors unless I add override before the func you gave me.

Comment: @joSimplemen yea, you will need to override it, the same as you have to for the `viewForHeader` delegate method.  If the answer solved your problem it’s good etiquette to accept it by clicking on the tick.

Answer (score 0):

```
override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return self.myTitles.count
}
```